# Why does the Stack Exchange app need permission to send MMS?

Tags: support, android-app

Why does the Stack Exchange app need the  permission 'send MMS'? I do not see why it would be needed.

- SE App Version: 1.0.85
- OS: Android / ArchOS

[image]

Comment: To send your feedback?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I doubt it, since that would make more sense to be 'send SMS' **and** I can't find anything *user-end* that uses the MMS permission.

Comment: Don't understand MMS either. Mail is more common I think. The iOS app uses email to send feedback too I think.

Comment: @PatrickHofman There is an IOS version? That's new (Android nutter, so I never know what happens on the apple side) Anyway, I'll block it for now. It won't be missed.

Comment: There is indeed. And it works quite well. Keep this question open. We will see what the devs have to say.

Comment: I have the Android App installed myself and it does not request MMS or Email permissions. It requests Contacts and Storage permissions. What version of Android are you using?

Comment: @animuson Marshmallow (6.0) I have never had those permissions asked. App is updated to latest version (because there has been no update in ages lol)

Comment: I'm running a 6.0.1-based ROM with SE app version 1.0.85 and also see the same as animuson. Privacy Guard does not list these capabilities for this app either.

Comment: @DanBrown Does it show you the same permissions when viewing the actual app in the Play Store? Are you using a carrier phone that might have a modified version of the OS? It sounds like the OS got messed up pretty badly if it's displaying two completely irrelevant permissions to you.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129179/why-does-every-app-has-needs-the-permission-send-mms-and-send-email /cc @animuson.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Do you really think SE has set up a mobile device just to receive feedback per SMS/MMS? I very much doubt that. The app can be used to give direct feedback here at Meta.SE, and email is much more suitable for feedback than SMS or MMS. I guess it's either some "low granularity" in the quite imperfect permission system, that something only vaguely related to SMS/MMS is covered by the same permission – or the app is compiled with a target SDK below MM, and the "default stuff" on showing permissions is messed up.

Comment: @animuson sorry for the wait- the app does indeed have It's 'normal permission set' on the play store. Reinstalling done little, so I got in contact with BUSH, and Argos (who own ArchOS, what my device runs) they said that other than minor modifications (bloatware, changed the system update agent, and a Always-encrypted policy) it is barely different to stock. Of course, I am using 1.0.85

Comment: @DanBrown take a look in the link I posted in the previous comment. This is something with your device. (Something about ROM / UI specific, not sure about technical details myself)

Comment: OK. So I found something odd: in permissions manager, the app requests MMS and email. In the app manager, it requests the more logical Contacts and Storage. The two do correlate- if I disable MMS, stack exchange cannot access my storage (likewise with email and contacts) @ShadowWizard is correct - it's a ROM bug, albeit a small one that is just a typo.